# VB Checking if a index of an Array exists

Tags: arrays, vb.net, integer

I was doing a console application in visual basic just for fun, and it has some commands, but when I try to check for an index like so: `if Words(1) Then` sinse it doesn't exist it just errors. Is there a function to check if it exists? Thank you.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's a bit unclear what the actual problem is that you're experiencing. Could you please define what you mean by _"exist"_ in this case? Do you mean that you want to check if the index is within the array bounds (between 0 and the index of the last item), or just if the item at that position is not null? Please also share the full error message that you're getting as that will help us understand the exact problem you're having.

Answer (score 1):

Just check the length of the array. If your index is greater than the size of the array it cant be in the array.

```
Dim words = New String(){"One", "Two"}
Dim index = 1
If words.Length > index Then 
    Console.Write(words(index))
End If
```

Comment: Good answer! I just have a thought: In case the OP (or anyone else, for that matter) is new to this it would perhaps be helpful to include just a short description of what `Length` actually indicates? Even though it seems to be self-explanatory to us, that might not be the case for everyone. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
   1: If (Not Words(x) Is Nothing) Then
   2: If Words.Length > 1 Then
```

**OR**

```
Private Sub myFunction()
     Dim Words() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4}
     Dim valueExists As Boolean = Array.Exists(Words, New Predicate(Of Integer)(AddressOf compareFunction))
End Sub

Private Function compareFunction(ByVal value As Integer) As Boolean
     Return (value = 4)  'Write your value to check'
End Function
```

Comment: Perfectly valid options! However it might perhaps be even more helpful to include a short description along with your code? If the OP (or any future readers, for that matter) is new to this, he/she might not fully understand what the code actually does.